# Al dar clic sobre nombre, mostrar información VUE.JS

Tags: vue.js, webservice

Buen día.

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto, en cual el usuario al dar clic sobre el nombre de una fuente, este le arroje información desde un webservices ya hecho.

Por el momento solo tengo la lista donde se encuentran las fuentes:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 pr-1"> 
        <DxDataGrid
            :ref="dataGridRef"
            :data-source="fuentes"
            :show-borders="false"
            :show-column-lines="false"
            :show-row-lines="false"
            :row-alternation-enabled="true"
            height="65vh"
            key-expr="ID_CONCEPTO"
        >
            <DxColumn data-field="DESC_VAR_CONCEPTUAL" caption="FUENTE" />            
            <DxPaging :enabled="false"/>
            <DxSelection
                select-all-mode="allPages"
                mode="multiple"
            />
            <DxSearchPanel :visible="true" :width="240" placeholder="Buscar..." />
        </DxDataGrid>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Alguien podría orientarme en como desarrollar la parte faltante?

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás usando la grilla de DevExpress puedes usar el evento de editar y sobreescribirlo, no sera dando click sobre el texto, pero si sobre cada fila habra una fila de comando que tendra su propio boton y servirá para el mismo efecto:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 pr-1">
      <DxDataGrid
        :ref="dataGridRef"
        :data-source="fuentes"
        :show-borders="false"
        :show-column-lines="false"
        :show-row-lines="false"
        :row-alternation-enabled="true"
        height="65vh"
        key-expr="ID_CONCEPTO"
        @editing-start="editRow"
      >
        <DxEditing :allow-updating="true" mode="row" />
        <DxColumn data-field="DESC_VAR_CONCEPTUAL" caption="FUENTE" />
        <DxPaging :enabled="false" />
        <DxSelection select-all-mode="allPages" mode="multiple" />
        <DxSearchPanel :visible="true" :width="240" placeholder="Buscar..." />
      </DxDataGrid>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    editRow(e) {
      row.cancel = true;
      console.log(e);
      // llamas al WS y haz lo que necesitas
    }
  }
};
</script>
```